# My text starts on a new page after the title and author list. How to fix it?

Tags: formatting, revtex, blank-page

If you run the following code, the core of my text starts on a new page, leaving a huge blank between the title and author and the bulk of the text (see the image below).

How can I fix it?

```
    \documentclass[pre,singlecolumn,amssymb,floatfix,superscriptaddress,footinbib,A4paper,longbibliography]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\ifpdf
\usepackage{epstopdf}   
\usepackage{url}
\fi
\newcommand{\squeezeup}{\vspace{-2.5mm}}

\begin{document}
\title{My paper title
}

\author{aa}
\email{aa@gmail.com}
\affiliation{bbbb}
\affiliation{cccc}

\author{dddd}
\affiliation{eeee}
\affiliation{ffff}
\maketitle

THE TEXT STARTS HERE. WHY IS IT ON THE NEXT PAGE?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The revtex4-1 manual is not exactly user friendly. I gave up on it. --- GOM

Comment: @Teepeemm I don't. Thanks a lot, this is a very simple solution.

Comment: I don't see `\begin{document}` before `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 1):

`revtex4-2` will put your text on the same page.  If you don't need `revtex4-1` (and it sounds like you don't), then you can make that switch.

(Your current preamble is giving a warning about "Unused global option(s): [singlecolumn,A4paper]."  They should be `onecolumn` and `a4paper` (with a lower case 'a'.)